# Hair Particle System to Create Forest: Some Trees are Floating

Tags: particles, hair

So I've got a problem popping up. I was following this video tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPOSAJuoEmU&index=3&list=PLvFQDY1Hrbb41mId9Evuvz3pDrHaGFDYI

I have noticed however that **many** of my trees are floating above the planes they are supposed to be growing from, which causes the immediate problem of shadows only appearing under some trees. I've checked around online, but most Q&A's similar to this one are because the person didn't use "Hair" or had their trees at the wrong orientation. I have tried to do what these other answers I have suggested but without much luck.

I don't mind if the distant trees float, but the ones on the closest mountain face are very obvious in the render. So any help would be great! If I have to I will just go through and manually move them if there is a way to do that! I just need them firmly in the ground, so to speak haha.

Photo time
[image: Trees are above planes causing no shadows to appear]

[image: Showing trees that are correct and trees that are wrong]

[image: These are the trees the particles are modelled from]

Comment: Are you using a displace modifier or another modifier that changes the surface the particles are emitting from? If so, you might need to check the modifier order to make the sure the particle system modifier is lower down and/or make sure 'Use Modifier Stack' is enabled on the particle system.

Comment: I can't believe the answer was one (obvious) click away, selecting "Use Modifier Stack" worked. Let me just put on this "Beginners" hat haha. Thank you so much. Literally, instantly fixed. The trees are even appearing according to my weight paint correctly now which was another issue I was ignoring lol (and why I have the number of particles cranked to 10,000)

I cannot believe it was that easy.

Comment: What other modifier are you using? I would like to write this up into an official answer (as opposed to a comment) so knowing *why* it worked would help.

Comment: Sure thing, the only modifier I had on the plane was "Decimate" with "triangulate" turned on. And I do have them in the correct order, with the "Decimate" on top and the "Particle System" underneath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the surface that the particles are emitted from is affected by another modifier then you will need to make sure that the particle system's modifier is *below* the other modifiers. This is so that the particle system can 'see' the previous modifier's result (because blender's modifiers execute in the order they are in the modifier 'stack', with each modifier passing on its data to the next).

Another option you may need is the *Use Modifier Stack*, found in the particle system's *Emission* panel. This makes sure the particle system is seeing the 'final result' of all the modifiers being applied to the object before trying to emit particles.